# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/........./RetroApp-debug.apk'

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I'm beginner in kivy library programming, but I have done very simple application, like in Kivy tutorial. On desktop it works cool. But than I wanted to do .apk file(Hadn't used Linux). I've tried a lot of steps to do an .apk file, but finally when I've installed and opened this program. It had an error. I've tried a lot of specs and new_android, but nothing worked. Finally I've updated my buildozer to the last version. But now, after buildozer android debug, he writes this error:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/kivy/reyyy/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/RetroApp/build/outputs/apk/RetroApp-debug.apk'.

*************buildozer.spec***************

```
[app]

title = Retro App

package.name = retroapp


package.domain = org.test

source.dir = .

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

version = 1.0

requirements = kivy

orientation = landscape

osx.python_version = 3

osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

fullscreen = 1

android.arch = armeabi-v7a

[buildozer]

log_level = 2

warn_on_root = 1
```

******python3: main.py*******

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty,ObjectProperty,ReferenceListProperty,StringProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from random import randint,choice


class RetryButton(Button):
    pass

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)

    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x,velocity_y)
    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity)+self.pos

class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self,ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx,vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height /10.0)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset

class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    win = NumericProperty(0)
    middle_rectangle_opacity = NumericProperty(1)
    winner = StringProperty('')
    def __init__(self,**q):
    super().__init__(**q)
        self.btn = RetryButton(width = self.width)
        self.btn.count = 0
        self.max_score = 10

    def serve_ball(self,vel = (10,0)):
        self.ball.center =  self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(*vel).rotate(choice([randint(0,30),randint(330,360)]))

    def update(self,dt):
        if self.win == 0:

            self.ball.move()
            self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
            self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)
            if self.player1.score >= self.max_score or self.player2.score >=self.max_score:
                if self.player1.score >= self.max_score:
                    self.winner = '1'
                else:
                    self.winner = '2'
                self.win = 1
                self.middle_rectangle_opacity = 0

            if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
                self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

            if self.ball.x<self.x:
                self.player2.score += 1
                self.serve_ball((10,0))
            if self.ball.x > self.width - self.ball.width:
                self.player1.score += 1
                self.serve_ball((-10,0))
        else:
            if self.btn.count == 0:
                self.btn.bind(on_press=self.retry)
                self.add_widget(self.btn)
                self.btn.count += 1

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width/3.0:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width/3.0:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y

    def retry(self,*q):

        self.player1.score = 0
        self.player2.score = 0
        self.win = 0
        self.middle_rectangle_opacity = 1
        self.serve_ball()
        self.remove_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn.count = 0

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1/30.0)
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()`
```

********KV pong.kv*********

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
<RetryButton>:
    text: 'Retry'
    font_size: 17
    size: self.width, '100dp'
<PongBall>:
    size:50,50
    canvas.before:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongPaddle>:
    size: '25dp','200dp'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size: self.size


<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,root.middle_rectangle_opacity
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.center_x - 5,0
            size: 10, self.height
    Label:
        font_size:35
        center_x: root.center_x
        center_y: root.height/4*3
        text: "Player {} wins!!".format(root.winner)
        color: 1,1,1,root.win
    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width/4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)
    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width/4*3
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)
    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y
    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width - self.width
        center_y: root.center_y
```

Please, help me!
Vadim.

Answer (score 1):

Please change your Python script as follow:

## main.py

```
class PongGame(Widget):
...
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
...

    def retry(self):
```

Since you are using Python 3.x, you need to do the following:

1. Install Buildozer with python3 support

   git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer

   cd buildozer

   python setup.py build

   sudo pip install -e .
2. Download and extract the Crystax NDK somewhere (~/opt/ is one option): https://www.crystax.net/en/download
3. Specify the following in your buildozer.spec:

## buildozer.spec

requirements = python3crystax,kivy

android.ndk = 10.3.2

android.ndk_path = /opt/crystax-ndk-10.3.2

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it's working. But I have 800 mb apk files, is it normal size for kivy apk?