# No such file or directory: .../myapp-debug.apk

Tags: python, virtual-machine, kivy, buildozer

I am not being able to build my application using Kivy/Buildozer Virtual Machine as getting an error in the last step

```
[DEBUG]:    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[DEBUG]:    Total time: 13 seconds
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    # Copying APK to current directory
[INFO]:    # Found APK file: /home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/bin/MyApp-0.1-debug.apk
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp /home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/bin/MyApp-0.1-debug.apk ./
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.34', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 104, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 212, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 817, in build_package
    copyfile(join(apk_dir, apk), join(self.buildozer.bin_dir, apk_dest))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/myapp/build/outputs/apk/myapp-debug.apk'
```

strong text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: u'/........./RetroApp-debug.apk'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272567/ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-u-retroapp-debug-apk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on first Kivy/Buildozer android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846023/error-on-first-kivy-buildozer-android-project)